# Selenium in Java: Not able to locate element on Amazon

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to get the text for Rating of any product on Amazon but I am unable to write the correct code. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Here its not even able to locate the element. 
Also I don't think xpath is wrong because I checked with Firepath.

Below is the code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Eclipse and workspace\\eclipse\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");

    WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox"));

    elem.sendKeys("Camera DSLR");

    driver.findElement(By.className("nav-input")).click();


    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='result_0']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/span/span/a/i[1]/span")));

    WebElement elem2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='result_0']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/span/span/a/i[1]/span"));
    elem2.getText();

}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: There are 2 elements with the class name `nav-input` a button and an input text. To which control does `driver.findElement(By.className("nav-input")).click();` this works?

Comment: yes it does.. only the last one doesn't. The last one is to get the rating of the product.

Comment: It does click and the next page opens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `span` element you want to get contains text like `"4.4 out of 5 stars"`, but actually you see just an icon with the stars, so it's bad idea to use `visibilityOfElementLocated` condition as it won't be visible anyway.

Try to use `presenceOfElementLocated` instead:

```
WebElement elem2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='a-popover-trigger a-declarative']//span[@class='a-icon-alt']")));
elem2.getAttribute("textContent");
```

*Note that to get text content of invisible span you should use `getAttribute("textContent")` instead of `getText()`*

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use dynamic xpath instead of absolute xpath:

`By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'a-icon-star')]//*[contains(@class,'a-icon-alt')]")`

And as [rightly pointed out by @Andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44226366/904375),

2. Use `presenceOfElementLocated` instead of `visibilityOfElementLocated` as tooltips are designed to be invisible.
3. Use `textContent` attribute for invisible elements such as tooltips instead of `getText()`.